# How do I fix a corrupt grouped_df?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with GPS tracking data from a tutorial for the `amt` package in R. (The code is also available [here](https://movebankworkshopraleighnc.netlify.com/rscripts) It's called TestVignetteMovebank2018.R)

When I run the code I get an error from the loop:

```
#' Load libraries
library(knitr)
library(lubridate)
library(raster)
library(move)
library(amt) 
library(ggmap)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

#' Create a login object for a user account at movebank.org
loginStored <- movebankLogin(username="MovebankWorkshop", password="genericuserforthisexercise")

#' Get overview information about a Movebank study. Be sure to check the citation and license terms if not using your own data.

getMovebankStudy(study="Martes pennanti LaPoint New York", login=loginStored) # see study-level info

#' Load data from a study in Movebank and create a MoveStack object. For more details and options see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/move/index.html.
fisher.move <- getMovebankData(study="Martes pennanti LaPoint New York", login=loginStored)
head(fisher.move)

#' Create a data frame from the MoveStack object
fisher.dat <- as(fisher.move, "data.frame")

#' ### Data cleaning
ind<-complete.cases(fisher.dat[,c("location_lat", "location_long", "timestamp")])
fisher.dat<-fisher.dat[ind==TRUE,]


#' Make timestamp a date/time variable
fisher.dat$timestamp<-as.POSIXct(fisher.dat$timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC")

#' ## Creating a track in amt
trk <- mk_track(fisher.dat, .x=location_long, .y=location_lat, .t=timestamp, id = local_identifier, 
                crs = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

# Now it is easy to calculate day/night with either movement track
trk <- trk %>% time_of_day()

#' Now, we can transform back to geographic coordinates
trk <- transform_coords(trk, CRS("+init=epsg:32618"))

trk.class<-class(trk)

nesttrk<-trk%>%nest(-id)

trk<-trk %>% nest(-id) %>% 
  mutate(dir_abs = map(data, direction_abs,full_circle=TRUE, zero="N"), 
         dir_rel = map(data, direction_rel), 
         sl = map(data, step_lengths),
         nsd_=map(data, nsd))%>%unnest()

trk<-trk%>% 
  mutate(
    week=week(t_),
    month = month(t_, label=TRUE), 
    year=year(t_),
    hour = hour(t_)
  )

class(trk)<-trk.class    

#' ## SSF prep

(timestats<-trk %>% nest(-id) %>% mutate(sr = map(data, summarize_sampling_rate)) %>%
    dplyr::select(id, sr) %>% unnest)

#' Time intervals range from every 2 to 15 minutes on average, depending
#' on the individual.  Lets add on the time difference to each obs.
trk<-trk %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(dt_ = t_ - lag(t_, default = NA))

#' THIS LOOP PRODUCES THE ERROR
ssfdat<-NULL
temptrk<-with(trk, track(x=x_, y=y_, t=t_, id=id))
uid<-unique(trk$id) # individual identifiers
luid<-length(uid) # number of unique individuals
for(i in 1:luid){
  # Subset individuals & regularize track
  temp<-temptrk%>% filter(id==uid[i]) %>% 
    track_resample(rate=minutes(round(timestats$median[i])), 
                   tolerance=minutes(max(10,round(timestats$median[i]/5))))

  # Get rid of any bursts without at least 2 points
  temp<-filter_min_n_burst(temp, 2)

  # burst steps
  stepstemp<-steps_by_burst(temp)

  # create random steps using fitted gamma and von mises distributions and append
  rnd_stps <- stepstemp %>%  random_steps(n = 15)

  # append id
  rnd_stps<-rnd_stps%>%mutate(id=uid[i])

  # append new data to data from other individuals
  ssfdat<-rbind(rnd_stps, ssfdat)
}
ssfdat<-as_tibble(ssfdat)
ssfdat
```

which produces the error message

> Error: `.data` is a corrupt grouped_df, the `"groups"` attribute must
>   be a data frame

This seems to be the result of a recent update to [dplyr](https://github.com/tidyverts/fable/issues/102) so that the `temp` object is no longer one that works with the functions that follow.

Do you know of a solution to this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide all code and data here not some external link. You can use `dput` for data.

Comment: I've added all of the code now. You can see that this will produce the data set.

Comment: Could you try to make your example minimal (and still self contained), that is, remove all code that doesn't directly demonstrate the problem? (Apologies if this contradicts NelsonGo's ask of providing _all_ code)

Comment: I've deleted some more code but I think the remainder is all necessary to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in the latest version of amt (on CRAN as of yesterday, I believe Windows and Mac builds may still be pending).